# OnCreateContextMenu not working with webview

Tags: xamarin.android

i have web-view that i need to create for it context menu when click on link type this what i did :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Webview);

    wv = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.WV);
    RegisterForContextMenu(wv);
    wv.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wv.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    wv.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
    wv.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
    wv.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;
    wv.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
    wv.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.Default;
    wv.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
    wv.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
    wv.SetInitialScale(1);

    wv.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");


     }



    public override void OnCreateContextMenu(IContextMenu menu, View v, IContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
   {
    base.OnCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    WebView webView = (WebView)v;
    result = webView.GetHitTestResult();


    if (result.GetType().ToString().Equals("SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE") || result.GetType().ToString().Equals("ANCHOR_TYPE"))
    {

        var item = menu.Add("copylink");
        item.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    }


}
```

but "result.GetType()" its its not detect anchor type link the "result.GetType()" is not detect any link in webview when it get pressed longtoch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a item to the menu, you should override `OnActionModeStarted` method. then add the `SetOnMenuItemClickListener`like following code.

```
   public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
    {
        IMenu menu = mode.Menu;
        menu.Add("Add To Notes");
        menu.GetItem(0).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(this));

        base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
    }

 internal class MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "You click the Add To Notes", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

If you want to create a new menu, you can use `menu.Clear();`

```
public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
    {
        IMenu menu = mode.Menu;
        menu.Clear();
        menu.Add("Add To Notes");
        menu.GetItem(0).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(this));

        base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
    }
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

**Update**

If you want to get the Type of long click, you should make sure type of `result.Type` is `Webkit.HitTestResult`, you use `result.GetType()`, Type is `System.Type`. So you can get the correct type, you can refer to the following code.

```
 WebView.HitTestResult result = webView.GetHitTestResult();
 Android.Webkit.HitTestResult myresult =  result.Type;
```

You can refer to the debug gif.
[image]

Comment: hi thanks for respond my issue is with the "result.GetType()" is not return the correct value when long click is triggered
if i toast it like this :
Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, result.GetType().ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
no matter where i click on webview always return as string value : "andiod.webkit.webview+hiTestresult"
i need to detect links in webview "AnchorType" but its not working

Comment: @جومارتميرزا I update my answer, you can refer to it.